# activemodel i18n & forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, activemodel

so i recently added my first translation other than english and now all my forms dont work.  upon further inspection, i found that it was trying to route to translated paths.  ie `users_path` was now `foobar_path` (foobar being the model translation)

i can update all my forms with `:url => users_path` but it seems like routing should not refer to the language files.

do i have my i18n setup configured incorrectly?  or is this a bug?

**EDIT**

so i realized that activerecord does NOT translate the routes, this is a problem with activemodel!

the fact that activerecord works as i would expect tells me that this is a bug with activemodel. has anyone had this issue before, and have suggestions for a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it!  i had some funcky model_name method defined for my activemodels.  replaced it with `extend ActiveModel::Naming`, now it behaves just like activerecord.